# Normal bundle in tangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let's consider the normal bundle $NM$ of zero section in $TM$. Is it true that $NM \cong TM$?

There is exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow TM \rightarrow TE|_M \rightarrow NM \rightarrow 0$$ for the normal bundle, but if $E=TM$... it's not exact.

Comment: Are you asking what the definition of the Euler and Thom class is or how to compute it in some examples?

Comment: No. Maybe I should reformulate... Let's consider the normal bundle $NM$ of zero section in $TM$. Is it true that $NM = TM$?

Comment: I think that isnt true. There is a natural symplectic structure on $TM$ and $M$ is lagrangian manifold. So, $NM = T^{*}M$. And we know that $TM \neq T^{*}M$, but we also know that the normal bundle for the zero section is our bundle... I'm confused.

Comment: The normal bundle of the zero section of $TM$ is not going to be all of $TM$, because it will only capture directions perpendicular to the manifold in $TM$.

Comment: Ok, and what about Euler characteristic? Is it true that the $\chi(NM) = -\chi(TM)$? And what means "not all"? It is 2-dimensional vector subbundle in 2-dimensional vector bundle...

Comment: Any vector bundle is homotopy equivalent to its zero section, so $\chi(NM) = \chi(TM) = \chi(M)$.

Comment: No. I mean $\chi(M) = \int_M e$, where $e$ is Euler class.

Comment: The answer to the question in the first line is "yes". What is the definition of the second non-trivial arrow in your exact sequence? And why do you think it is not exact?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually a  much more general result is true:  given a manifold $M$ and an arbitrary vector bundle $E\stackrel {\pi}{\to} M$ on $M$, the normal vector bundle $N_E(M)$   of $M$ (identified with the zero section of $E$) in $E$ is isomorphic to $E$.
 In other words we have a direct sum decomposition of vector bundles  on $M$:

$$T(E)|M =T(M)\oplus   E                     $$

The key to understanding this is to consider the case where $M$ is reduced to a point: it is then the result which says that the tangent  space at the origin $T_0E$ of a vector space $E$      can be identified with the vector space $E$ itself.
Indeed, if  tangent vectors are defined  (say) as derivations, then  the vector $v\in E$ is identified with  the derivation $\partial _v|_0$ which sends the function $f$ to its directional derivative $$\partial _vf(0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac {f(tv)-f(0)}{t}$$ 
**Edit**
It might be of interest to notice that associated to any vector bundle $E\stackrel {\pi}{\to} M$  we have a canonical  exact sequence of bundles **on** $\textbf E$ : $$0\to\pi^*(E)\to T(E)\to \pi^*(T(M))\to 0  $$ The vector bundle $\pi^*(E)=:T_{vert}(E)$ is the subvector bundle of $T(E)$ consisting of vectors tangent to the fibers of $\pi$.
Restricting this exact sequence to the zero section of the bundle identified with $M$ we get the canonical exact sequence of bundles **on** $\textbf M$: $$0\to E\to T(E)\vert M\to T(M)\to 0$$ 
This exact sequence can **non canonically**  be split and we obtain the already mentioned decomposition $T(E)|M =T(M)\oplus E$ .

Comment: So, in our case this decomposition is $(TE)|_M = TM \oplus TM$? There is exact sequence $0 \rightarrow TM \rightarrow TM \oplus TM \rightarrow TM$. Ok. And what about symplectic strucutre? The normal bunlde of lagrangian manifold $NM$ isomorphic to a cotanget bundle $T^{*}M$. So, we have $TM = T^*M$.

Comment: Dear Gleb, your question had nothing to do with symplectic structures. I suggest you ask another question if you want to know something about these.

Comment: The last exact sequence in this answer actually **does split canonically** (i.e. once restricted to the zero section). It's enough to provide a section of the projection $T(E)\rvert M \to T(M)$; the derivative of the zero section itself suffices for this purpose. If $[\gamma(t)]$ is the equivalence class of a curve $\gamma(t) : \mathbb{R} \to E$ representing a tangent vector in $T(E)\rvert M$, then the corresponding map $T(E)\rvert M \to E$ is defined by$$
[\gamma(t)]\mapsto\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\gamma(t)}{t}.
$$
Since $\gamma(0) = 0$ (i.e. lies in the zero section), this is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension count argument I gave is wrong. If $Z:M\hookrightarrow TM$, then $NM = Z^*(TTM)/TM$ does indeed have the right dimension. The intuition is wrong because the directions in $TM$ "perpendicular" to $M$ are exactly the tangent directions.